# CS0108 warning with DataGridView column name

Tags: c#, datagridview, compiler-warnings

I have a DataGridView with a column named "Location" (same as database field.) When compiling, I get the CS0108 warning. Here are the relevant parts of the form designer:

```
Form1Designer.cs(271,64,271,72): warning CS0108: 'Form1.Location' hides inherited member 'Form.Location'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.Location = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            ...
            // 
            // dataGridView1
            // 
            this.dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
            this.Location,
            ...
            // 
            // Location
            // 
            this.Location.DataPropertyName = "Location";
            this.Location.HeaderText = "Location";
            this.Location.Name = "Location";
            this.Location.ReadOnly = true;
            this.Location.Visible = false;
        }

        #endregion
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Location;
```

Comment: Change the control name from `Location` to something else.

Answer (score 0):

This warning is specific to the “designer” code. Another example of this issue is if (in the designer) you try to set a grids column “Name” property to “Name.” In this case (in the designer code), the compiler will throw an implicit conversion to `string` exception on the line `this.Name = "Form1";.` The “designer” is looking at… `this.Name” … as the grids COLUMN, NOT the “forms.Name” property. Hence the compilers confusion.

The reason you are getting a warning and NOT a conversion error is because you did not “change” the “FORMS” default “Location” property. If (in the designer) you click on the “FORM” and change its “Location” property to something like X=10, Y=10, THEN when you compile the code… you will get an exception as shown below…

[image]

As already noted, the compiler is looking at `this.Location` as the COLUMN, and NOT the forms `Location` property.

In other words, ALL these issues are coming from “when” the “designer” code is run and its confusion when naming columns to the same name as the form’s property names. I will assume this is a “bug,” since there should be a clear distinction about “which” object “this” is… however, it is not difficult to see “why” there is some confusion.

As already commented, you can change the columns name to something else… OR … you can add the columns IN CODE AFTER the form’s constructor has called the `InitializeComponent();` method. Obviously, in code, you cannot add the columns to the grid BEFORE the form’s constructor calls the `InitializeComponent();` method, however, if you add the columns “in code” AFTER the `InitializeComponent();` method has been called, like the forms `Load` event or in the form’s constructor, then it will work as expected without errors or warnings.